# Why is this mod_rewrite redirecting my domain?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to redirect all URLs past the "/" of my domain to an old.mysite.com version, but leave the mysite.com itself alone.

For example, "mysite.com" -> "mysite.com", but "mysite.com/some-url" -> "old.mysite.com/some-url". Here's what I have now:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.+)$
RewriteRule /(.*) http://archived.example.com/$1
```

But it's redirecting "mysite.com" -> "old.mysite.com". How can I modify this so that the core domain doesn't get redirected, but only when there are URL bits past the ".com/" so to speak?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.+)$` matches all characters after the `/`

`(.+)` is a regular expression that matches any character.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/[a-zA-Z0-9\/-]+$
RewriteRule /(.*) http://archived.example.com/$1
```

The above might do it, but I'm not very good with regular expressions.

`[a-zA-Z0-9\/-]+` will match a series of any of the characters in the brackets following the trailing `/`.

I use [RegExLib](http://regexlib.com/Default.aspx) as my cheat-sheet. It'll also let you test regular expressions against a source (to see what matches).

Comment: Nathan - Thanks for the response. From my understanding, (.+) matches any character (but must be at least 1 character). My thinking was that I didn't want to redirect to archived.example.com *unless* there were characters after the slash, because I wanted just "example.com" to stay "example.com" if that makes sense. Thanks again for helping...

Comment: It makes perfect sense. And I've confused myself. Will revisit a bit later.

Comment: Nathan, you steered me on the right track by pointing out that I was matching *everything* (including spaces). I fixed my regex to read: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/[a-zA-Z0-9\/-]+$ and all is working now. Thanks!

Comment: That's great! I learned a little something, too! I've edited my answer, above, with your contribution, so maybe if someone else comes along it'll be helpful! I thought about including `[a-zA-Z0-9\/-]+`, but what confused me was whether we should be matching the entire URL or only what followed the trailing `/`. If I'd read the [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) more closely, it might have helped! Glad we got it figured out!